# Understanding an example of PyTorch's Einsum function

Tags: pytorch

I am studying some code and I came across a usage of PyTorch's einsum function that I am not understanding. The docs are [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.einsum.html).

The snippet looks like (slightly modified from the original):

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(64, 64, 25, 25)
y = torch.rand(64, 64, 64, 25)
result = torch.einsum('ncuv,nctv->nctu', x, y)
print(result.shape)
>> torch.Size([64, 64, 64, 25])
```

So the notation is such that n=64, c=64, u=25, v=25, t=64.

I'm not too sure what's happening. I think that for each 25 dimensional vector in t (64 of them), each one is being multiplied with each of the u=25 vectors of size 25 elementwise and then the results summed, or rather 25 dot products of 25 dimensional vectors?

Any insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can think of it as taking dot products over certain dimensions, and reorganizing the rest.

For simplicity, let's ignore the batching dimensions `n` and `c` (since they are consistent before and after `ncuv,nctv->nctu`), and discuss:

```py
import torch
x = torch.rand(25, 25)
y = torch.rand(64, 25)
result = torch.einsum('uv,tv->tu', x, y)
print(result.shape)
>> torch.Size([64, 25])
```

Note that `v` vanishes after einsum, meaning `v` is the dimension being summed up, while `t` and `u` are not. You can interpret it this way: `x` is a  collection of `25` 25-dimensional vectors; `y` is a collection of `64` 25-dimensional vectors. The dot product of the `t`-th vector in `y` and the `u`-th vector in `x` are computed and put in the `t`-th row and `u`-th column of `result`.

You can also rewrite into a math equation:

```
result[n,c,t,u] = \sum_{v} x[n,c,u,v] * y[n,c,t,v], for each n, c, t, u
```

Note two things:

- the summation is over the indices that vanish in the summation pattern `nctu,ncuv->nctv`
- indices appearing on the right of the pattern are the indices of the resulting tensor

Comment: Very well written answer, thanks for your help.